No buds to judge where to prune on established rosebush
I need to deadhead my floribunda David Austin rose but am not finding and new buds above the 5 leaf stem to judge my cut.
The rose was lovely for the first flush but I’m not seeing any fresh red buds?
Any ideas?
Thank you 

Hi David, and welcome to the site.  A picture of your rose would help people give you better advice.

Thanks Mack, trying to figure out how to load a picture down on this site

They don't make it easy on you!  Here is a guide to uploading pictures.  https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-post-images-here

Went to the help website and unfortunately not seeing the box with a mountain image on the top row of this app to download my image.

Thanks for your time however Mack. Much appreciated

You need to "[edit]" your question to get the box with the mountain icon. Link is right under your question.
